# Fast Audio Waveform Visualizer

Tags: performance, audio, visualization, waveform

I am trying to make a program to **display the waveform of audio**. The problem is **audio has a lot of samples** and while drawing every single one would result in what I am looking for it would take too much time. This picture from audacity is basically what I am looking for...

[image]

I could precompute the waveform some how, but I still need to be able to **zoom in and out**...

[image]

Are there methods (probably requiring you to precompute something) to be able to display an **accurate waveform quickly** and be able to zoom in to single samples and out to view the whole file?

How do programs, like audacity for example, do it? What are **good resources** to look into to learn more about this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: slick tools like Audacity are written in compiled languages and use OpenGL ... if you must target the browser then avoid writing to Canvas, instead use WebGL which is extremely fast and is a direct descendent of OpenGL ... see audio plotting with WebGL at https://webgl-3d-animation.herokuapp.com/

Comment: however I suggest you use any language you are comfortable in and just use whatever is available to draw a straight line to implement the audio curve plot ... hardware is so fast today that you will be surprised how responsive your plot can be ... get a mono WAV format file open it up and populate an array with the integer values which represent height of the raw audio curve ... just output to the console before plotting .. write your own WAV file with your own sin curve so you have an input file with known data only then worry about plotting the curve .. use any language at all ... just do it